# IBM x3200 M3 memory upgrade

Tags: memory, ibm

I try to update the RAM memory of an IBM x3200 M3 - 7328AC1 server.

Currently it has two [Kingston 2GB 240-Pin DDR3 registered ECR SDRAM](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820139127) and when I switched to fourth [HYNIX HMT151R7BFR4C-H9 4GB](https://www.serversupply.com/MEMORY/PC3-10600/4GB/HYNIX/HMT151R7BFR4C-H9.htm) the server does not pass the "uefi starting" screen. I also tried one at a time without success.

When I return the Kingston memories, I see the error in the log [S 51004] but I can not find any description of this error.

[Picture of the Kingston](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UUni.jpg)

Comment: Why are you running a 13.5 year old server in Production?

Comment: Is a server for a small warehouse in the thirdh world :P , Uruguay.

Comment: Still very unprofessional to use unsupported kit

Comment: Yes, I still have a lot to learn...
Can you help me with this? What is the memory that I need to find?

Comment: That's the point - you're going to struggle to find anything that does work, it's that old. Try to buy supported memory modules, not just something that sounds like it might work.